# C# ComboBox displays in incorrect position

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

`ComboBox` will work perfectly on my computer like this:

[image]

But it will display in wrong position on specific computer like this:

[image]

You can notice the wrong position in the picture. It displays a little bigger than the correct position in the picture and the values display always on the left side of `ComboBox`. The `ComboBox` is located within a panel. If I use the `ComboBox` in a new `Form`, it works perfectly.

It will display in wrong position until I restart the program. Only `SelectedIndexChange` event on the `ComboBox`. But it will happen on no event `ComboBox`...

It will happen when following the steps below:

1. Click one `ComboBox`.
2. Click another `ComboBox`.
3. Back to the `ComboBox` in Step 1 and click. Done.

I am using C#, .NET 4.5, Visual Studio 2013, on Windows 8.1.

Comment: is any component set to right-to-left?

Comment: I edited your question to clarify some points, but you lost me here: "It will display in wrong position until I restart the program. Only SelectedIndexChange event on the ComboBox. But it will happen on no event ComboBox..."  Please review to make it more clear. Also, wait for the edit to be approved, might take some time.

Comment: @TaW : Only `MenuStrip`.Some `ToolStripMenuItem` Alignment is Right. Thank you.

Comment: @Sabuncu : I mean no matter event register on `ComboBox` or not, it will display incorrect position. Thank you.